# Why can't spring boot/data automagically configure multiple data sources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot app that connects to two databases. **Everything works fine.**

My package structure looks like the following

```
- db
  - bar
    - BarDbConfig.java
    - domain
      - BarModel.java
    - repo
      - BarRepo.java
  - foo
    - FooDbConfig.java
    - domain
      - FooModel.java
    - repo
      - FooRepo.java
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

#first db
bar.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:h2:C:\\Project\\com.example\\db3.data
bar.datasource.username=admin
bar.datasource.password=admin
bar.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

#second db
foo.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:h2:C:\\Project\\com.example\\db2.data
foo.datasource.username=admin
foo.datasource.password=admin
foo.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

BarDbConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager"
)
public class BarDbConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar.datasource")
    public DataSource barDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages(BarDbConfig.class.getPackage().getName())
                .persistenceUnit("barPersistenceUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

FooDbConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "fooEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "fooTransactionManager"
)
public class FooDbConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.datasource")
    public DataSource fooDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fooEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("fooDataSource") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages(FooDbConfig.class.getPackage().getName())
                .persistenceUnit("fooPersistenceUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager fooTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("fooEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

However, I was wondering if all this boilerplate code was really necessary?

- Isn't there any way to remove all the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `PlatformTransactionManager` stuff?
- Is there any reason why it is necessary to provide all those explicit `Qualifier`-names?
- Can't spring boot find and autoconfigure the datasources  by it self??
- What would be the absolute minimal code required to connect to two databases utilizing convention over configuration?

Comment: 'back in the day' this would all be done in XML. however to do what you need(Multiple Datasources)..you need the Annotations you are currently using....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to answer the one question you ask in the title and then again in the body of your question:

> Can't spring boot find and autoconfigure the `DataSource`s by itself?

99% of applications use one database and these cases it is pretty obvious what you want to happen and that's what Boot does for you.

If you have 2 databases in your application there are many questions that don't have reasonable default answers:

Which repositories should use which `DataSource`? Split by package? Have two repositories for each interface? Have a routing `DataSource`? By what criterium should it route the requests?

Do you want one transaction across multiple `DataSource`s or separate ones? Or maybe both for different use cases?

Of course, Boot could pick one possible answer for all these questions but the result would be only helpful for a small subset of an already small group of developers.
Therefore it isn't done.

Of course, if you find something that is almost always done in a certain way, I'm sure the Spring Boot developers appreciate a feature request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So it's the shortest way of handeling multiple data sources.

But still wondering why they did not implement this, cause the code I posted, is how all the tutorials are doing it. So propbably 99% of the people using multiple data sources are doing it like i do.
But anyway, thank you